# How to clip and concatenate a page region in multiple pdf files with one page each?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have a lot of pdf files each one with an image inside. I want to clip a rectangular region in each of these files and concatenate them into a single pdf file. Is it possible with ghostscript or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a go at this. Try [Briss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/) if you want to crop rectangular regions in pdf files. It's free and cross-platform GUI.

[image]

If you have multiple pdf files you can concatenate/merge them first online using http://www.pdfmerge.com/ Then use Briss to crop the images out into a new pdf file. Or vice-versa depending on the location of your images inside the pdf files.

After you fire up Briss, load the merged pdf file containing the images. When you're asked if you want to exlude anything, just click "cancel" if you want to include all pages.

If your file has many pages, similar pages may be overlapping each other so you can draw a rectangle over the region you want to crop. Click `Action` -> `Preview` for previewing the output. Click `Action` -> `Crop PDF` to finalize your output pdf file. Cheers.